# Why is my list only collecting the first input?

Tags: python, list

Im trying to make a list of all the purchases i have made in the past and viewing them in a list format, and whenever i try put a invalid statement into the list its supposed to reject that statement and prompt for a new input, but instead its just grabbing the first input and storing that instead.

if i input w, x, y, z but have to reinput z because it was invalid, (m would be changed value) the
output would still be w,x,y,z unchanged,
how do i get the list to print w,x,y,m?

```
def check_if_valid_number(item_being_tested, Error_Message1, Maximum, Minimum):
    if item_being_tested.isnumeric() == False:
        while item_being_tested.isnumeric() == False:
            print(Error_Message1)
            time.sleep(.3)
            print("Please try again:")
            item_being_tested = input()
    int_number_value = int(item_being_tested)
    if int_number_value > Maximum or int_number_value < Minimum:
        while int(item_being_tested) > Maximum or int(item_being_tested) < Minimum:
            print(Error_Message1)
            time.sleep(.3)
            print("Please try again:")
            item_being_tested = input()
            if item_being_tested.isnumeric() == False:
                while item_being_tested.isnumeric() == False:
                    print(Error_Message1)
                    time.sleep(.3)
                    print("Please try again:")
                    item_being_tested = input()
```

Function checks if it is a valid number

```
month = input("month:")
check_if_valid_number(month, "Month must be between 1-12 and not include letters", 12, 1)
day = input("day:")
check_if_valid_number(day, "Day must be between 1-31 and not include letters", 31, 1)
year = input("year:")
check_if_valid_number(year, "Year cannot include letters", inf, inf)
dates.append("{}/{}/{}".format(month,day,year))
```

in this example, even if i put 33 as a input first, then change it to 5, the list will store 33

Comment: Hi & welcome as a contributor, Peter. Just a comment on your question - that's quite a lot of code. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and see if you can reduce / simplify it at all. You will almost certainly get more useful responses if you're able to do so. In fact this approach often helps you find the problem yourself...

Comment: It's also helpful to provide sample input vs. output.

Comment: The bottom and second to top text are the io

Answer (score 0):

`check_if_valid_number()` needs to return the updated value, then you can assign that back to the variable.

```
def check_if_valid_number(item_being_tested, Error_Message1, Maximum, Minimum):
    if item_being_tested.isnumeric() == False:
        while item_being_tested.isnumeric() == False:
            print(Error_Message1)
            time.sleep(.3)
            print("Please try again:")
            item_being_tested = input()
    while int(item_being_tested) > Maximum or int(item_being_tested) < Minimum:
        print(Error_Message1)
        time.sleep(.3)
        print("Please try again:")
        item_being_tested = input()
        if item_being_tested.isnumeric() == False:
            while item_being_tested.isnumeric() == False:
                print(Error_Message1)
                time.sleep(.3)
                print("Please try again:")
                item_being_tested = input()
    return int(item_being_tested)

month = check_if_valid_number(input("month:"), "Month must be between 1-12 and not include letters", 12, 1)
day = check_if_valid_number(input("day:"), "Day must be between 1-31 and not include letters", 31, 1)
year = check_if_valid_number(input("year:"), "Year cannot include letters", inf, inf)
dates.append("{}/{}/{}".format(month,day,year))
```

There's no need for this line:

```
    if int_number_value > Maximum or int_number_value < Minimum:
```

since it's duplicated by the condition of the `while` loop.